# PostgreSQL Type 1 interface and ImageMagick code - conflicting StringInfo definitions?

Tags: c, postgresql, types, imagemagick

Running into a problem here, trying to integrate a code snippet from ImageMagick into PostgreSQL; the two 'frameworks' use a definintion of StringInfo - and of course, they conflict.

At make, get this error:

```
 /usr/include/magick/string_.h:42: error: conflicting types for 'StringInfo'
 ../../src/include/lib/stringinfo.h:43: error: previous declaration of 'StringInfo' was here
```

Any suggestions on how I might marry the two?

```
typedef struct _StringInfo
{
  char
    path[MaxTextExtent];

  unsigned char
    *datum;

  size_t
    length;

  unsigned long
    signature;
} StringInfo;
```

And PostgreSQL wants to do this:

```
typedef struct StringInfoData
{
    char       *data;
    int         len;
    int         maxlen;
    int         cursor;
} StringInfoData;

typedef StringInfoData *StringInfo;


/*------------------------
 * There are two ways to create a StringInfo object initially:
 *
 * StringInfo stringptr = makeStringInfo();
 *      Both the StringInfoData and the data buffer are palloc'd.
 *
 * StringInfoData string;
 * initStringInfo(&string);
 *      The data buffer is palloc'd but the StringInfoData is just local.
 *      This is the easiest approach for a StringInfo object that will
 *      only live as long as the current routine.
 *
 * To destroy a StringInfo, pfree() the data buffer, and then pfree() the
 * StringInfoData if it was palloc'd.  There's no special support for this.
 *
 * NOTE: some routines build up a string using StringInfo, and then
 * release the StringInfoData but return the data string itself to their
 * caller.  At that point the data string looks like a plain palloc'd
 * string.
 *-------------------------
 */

/*------------------------
 * makeStringInfo
 * Create an empty 'StringInfoData' & return a pointer to it.
 */
extern StringInfo makeStringInfo(void);

/*------------------------
 * initStringInfo
 * Initialize a StringInfoData struct (with previously undefined contents)
 * to describe an empty string.
 */
extern void initStringInfo(StringInfo str);

/*------------------------
 * resetStringInfo
 * Clears the current content of the StringInfo, if any. The
 * StringInfo remains valid.
 */
extern void resetStringInfo(StringInfo str);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the obvious answer is to try hard not to marry the two at all, but rather to look at the possibility of compiling the ImageMagick code into a .so and linking to that with a narrower set of interfaces in your PostgreSQL code.  This way StringInfo need not be present in your bridging code at all or if you need it, you can define it using a different name.

The other option is to change the name on the ImageMagick side, and make sure you change the code in all the appropriate places.  However that makes it a lot harder to merge in new versions of the program.   I would highly recommend trying instead to use the modularized approach of trying to ensure that the two never share a scope.